# Why did Fitzgerald cut off the captain's scalp?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-revenant

When Captain Henry and Glass head out to find Fitzgerald, they separate and the captain encounters Fitzgerald alone.

[image: Captain Henry and Fitzgerald's encounter]

They both start shooting each other simultaneously, but we don't notice that the captain was shot until Glass finds him dead, with his scalp cut off.

There was a scene where Bridger asked Fitzgerald about his scalp, and he answered: "Rees took it off."

[image: Fitzgerald and Bridger talking]

Now I'm not sure why he did the same thing to the captain. Was he lying about Rees taking it off? Was it out of anger? Or is there any other reasons I didn't notice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fitzgerald likely scalped the Captain so as to make it look like the Ree had killed the Captain. Furthermore, much like how a victim of abuse can then become an abuser, Fitzgerald seems to be emotionally scarred by the half-scalping he received from the Ree and has adopted that method to exact pain and punishment on his victim.